# Order shows as guest customer

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, sales-order, customer-account

I am using **Magento-EE 2.1.5** and facing one strange issue. Order placed by **registered customer** shows as a guest's one. When I dig in deep, I find that `sales_order` table's column `customer_firstname` is not updated when a quote is converted into an order. I checked that the quote table has the correct customer name for the corresponding order. Anyone have an idea about this issue resolution? [image: screen shot]

Comment: It is possible that registered customer can also place order using guest checkout and if customer placed order after logged in there should be an entry with customer_id in database in sales_flat_order table. can you check is it there?

Comment: Order places as register customer,even customer email getting correctly.   Issue is only customer_firstname, and customer_lastname not transferring from quote table to sales_order table

Answer (score 0):

I found the cause, cause was cart2quote extension was the reason of this issue with enterprise edition.